# Is there a function in R to rename rows by groups with increasing numbers

Tags: r, rename, rows

I have a very simple data frame [36, 4], and I'd like to rename rows of one column:
see column "Ab_type" in the attached image

I'd like to rename the 36 rows of column "Ab_type" by groups of 4  (e.g. Ab1_1, Ab1_2, Ab1_3, Ab1_4, Ab2_1, Ab2_2, Ab2_3, Ab2_4,....Isotype_1, Isotype_2, Isotype_3, Isotype_4).

Would you have any suggestion?
I'm completely new to coding.
Many thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNiC2.png)

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular, note that images should NOT be used as the only way to present data since it makes it difficult for anyone else to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
df1$Ab_type <- sub("-", "", sub("-[^-]+$", "", df1$Ab_type))
df1$Ab_type <- with(df1, paste0(Ab_type, "_", 
     ave(seq_along(Ab_type), Ab_type, FUN = seq_along)))
```